# Get just the x or y pos with pygame.mouse.get_pos

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I want to know how to get the x-coordinate position or the y-coordinate position of the mouse individually on pygame. 
Like just the x and just the y. I think It would use

```
pygame.mouse.get_pos
```

Answer (score 1):

Pygame doesn't have an API that will get you only one coordinate, you always get both. But it returns them in a 2-tuple, so you can index to get just one value if you want to:

```
x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
```

If there's any chance you might need the `y` coordinate as well, it might make sense to unpack as normal anyway, and just ignore the `y` value in the part of the code where you don't need it:

```
x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

# do stuff with x, ignore y

if something_rare_happens():
    # do stuff with y too
```

It might even be clearer to do the unpacking even if you'll *never* use `y`, but that's really up to you.